# end of line character is not detected

Tags: c, string

A simple program, a static string which is used to read the input, then pass it to the function. Just wondering why it can not find the '\0' character using the while(*string!='\0') expression.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int is_palindrome(char *string)
{
    int length, mid, end, i;
    length=0;
    if (string == NULL)
        return 0;

    while (string[length] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c\n", string[length]);
        length++;

    }
    //Not working version
    /*
    while(*string!='\0')
        length++;
    */

    end = length - 1;
    mid = length / 2;
    printf(" end=%d, mid=%d\n", end, mid);
    for (i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
        if (string[i] != string[end]) {
            printf("It's not palindrome\n");
            return 0;
        }
        end--;
    }

    if (i == mid) {
        printf("It's palindrome\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a string to test for the parlindrome\n");
    gets(string);

    int length = strlen(string);
    printf("You entered %s,length is %d\n", string, length);
    if (is_palindrome(string))
        ;
    printf("Enter to Quit\n");
    char x;
    scanf("%c", &x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  You should use `fgets` instead.

Comment: I even manually added a '\0' at the end, after gets. But it still doesn't work

Comment: `gets()` isn't the cause of the problem with the `'\0'`; it does properly null-terminate the input buffer. But it's inherently unsafe, because it doesn't guard against overly long input; it's a buffer overflow waiting to happen. It's even been removed from C in the latest version of the standard. Using `fgets()` rather than `gets()` won't solve the problem you're asking about, but do it anyway. (`fgets()` leaves the `'\n'` character in the string, so you'll have to deal with that.)

Comment: Your title refers to an "end of line character". `'\0'` marks the end of a *string*, not the end of a line. `'\n'` marks the end of a line in a text stream. (As I mentioned, you will have to deal with `'\n'` if you use `fgets`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
while(*string!='\0')
  length++;
```

write

```
char* p = string;
while( *p++ )
  length++;
```

otherwise the pointer will not move and you become stuck in an infinite loop (if the string is not empty). Use `p` to avoid changing the original pointer.

Also initialize all variables before using them, good rule of thumb.

Comment: no it will not, if length is originally 0 and the string is empty, length will remain 0 since *p will be 0.

Comment: I stand (sit actually) corrected. `p` does increment, but `length` does not. totally my bad. I still had it in my head the utter uselessness of `length` to begin with, since `while (*p) ++p;` followed by `(p-string)` delivers the length without the extra var. I totally apologize. Folk with 17K rep don't make mistakes like that (but apparently ones with 14K rep *do* =P). (and +1, nice answer).

Comment: thanks, no problem - it is not like i haven't done the same oversight about 123123 times :)

Comment: LOL followed shortly after with the whole "wtf was I thinking?" self-deprecation. Haven't we all, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `length` to 0 before using its value in the `while` loop.

Or you could use the standard library function `strlen()`.

Also, in the palindrome check, you should probably decrease `end` at the same you increase `i`. As it is, you're comparing the characters in the first half each with the same char at the end. This will match strings like "aaaabfa" but not "abcdcba".

Comment: the length variable in main()? Does effect the string formation?

Comment: The length variable that you use in the loop that's not working. Perhaps you intended to use `i` and then set `length = i;` later.

Comment: sorry about the length assignment, it was not originally used. I modified my code, and added the part that does not work, can you take a look

Comment: Oh. I completely ignored the comment. I was talking about the replacement that uses `string[length]`. And I meant `while` loop, not `for` loop.